# When to use Doctrine_Table vs regular model class?

Tags: model, doctrine

I'm trying to understand when is the appropriate time to use Doctine_Table classes and which methods to store there vs. in the regular model class file.

Also, is it good practice to use the findBy* methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use methods in the model class that operate on an instance of that model - a user record that you've retrieved, a blog post etc.  For example, you may have a `setPassword()` method on a user record, which sets the password for that user using your own algorithm, or a `getTitleUppercased()` method on a blog post which returns the blog title but uppercased.

Methods on the table class are used for operating on the table as a whole - generally, you'll find query methods here that aren't available via the Doctrine magic methods.  Queries that involve specific joins, specific parameters (eg `WHERE date > NOW() AND foo.bar < 5`) should go in here.

It's good practice to use the `findBy*` methods if your query is simple - don't reinvent the wheel.  Note that these are quite specific, so it's great for things like `findOneByEmail('test@example.com')`, but if you need to be more specific, move your query into the table class into its own method.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! That really clears things up for me. Your examples were very helpful.